# Column level role access in SQL Server 2014 using Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

So a friend of mine is on a new project. The customer wants to use SQL Server roles (admin, poweruser, superior, general, guest) and wants to have restriction on which columns to a table can be pulled back when the user has this role.

Imagine a table below

```
ID  Make    Model   Type    ProdCost    ROI Frequency   RecallDate
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1   70      This    1       $12         2   2   
2   71      That    2       $12         3   2   
3   72      Sparrow 3       $12         2   3   
4   72      Duck    4       $12         2   N/a 
5   76      Fellon  5       $12         4
```

- Admin role can retrieve all columns
- Poweruser can retrieve all columns except `ID`
- Guest can get `ID MAKE Model` columns
- General gets `ID, ProdCost, ROI, Frequency, RecallDate`

How do we make this work with Entity Framework? Ideas? The client wants to use views but it all seems messy

Comment: That sounds more like a presentation tier concern (i.e. done in your MVC Razor Views or Controller) than something to be done with Databases or EF. You can simply hide the columns in Razor to which the user isn't permitted to see.

Comment: thats how we normally do it, however this customer is worried about some PII

Comment: Views as in Data Base Views not MVC Views